# If A and B are positive semidefinite matrices, then $\mathrm{tr}( A^3B + AB^3)\ge 2\mathrm{tr}( A^2B^2)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

We know the following relationship: If A and B are positive semidefinite matrices, then $\mathrm{tr}(AB)^2\le\mathrm{tr}(A^2B^2)$.

How can I prove this relationship?
If A and B are positive semidefinite matrices, then $$\mathrm{tr}(A^3B + AB^3)\ge 2 \mathrm{tr}( A^2B^2).$$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Assuming these are Hermitian positive definite, you can get this by using the standard Hilbert Schmidt Inner Product, then Cauchy-Schwarz.  Some effort is expected in the original post. so I've voted to close.

Comment: @user8675309 Your comment is cryptic.

Comment: Use the tracial property to prove that $LHS-RHS=\operatorname{tr}\left(A^{1/2}(A-B)B(A-B)A^{1/2}\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

In fact this follows easily from that the matrices are diagonalizable in an orthogonal basis , have non-negative eigenvalues, and that $x^3y+xy^3- 2y^2x^2\ge 0$ for $x\ge 0,y\ge 0$.

$$A = \sum_{i=1}^n a_iu_i u_i^\top,\qquad
B=\sum_{j=1}^n b_jv_j v_j^\top$$
So
$$A^k = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^ku_i u_i^\top,\qquad
B^m=\sum_{j=1}^n b_j^mv_j v_j^\top$$
and
$$Tr(A^3B+AB^3-2A^2B^2) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n (a_i^3b_j+a_i b_j^3-2a_i^2 b_j^2) Tr(u_i u_i^\top v_j v_j^\top)$$

Conclude with $Tr(u_i u_i^\top v_j v_j^\top)=(u_i^\top v_j)^2$.